# Swagger Flask Python3, JSON $ref not including external file

Tags: python-3.x, flask, openapi

References to internal sections in *swagger.json* work correctly, but attempting to reference a JSON file in the same directory seems to be ignored. I have some large *example* data files so would like to reference them instead of including them in the *swagger.json* file.

How do I get swagger to dereference the $ref tags for external files in the ./static/ directory (this is the same location as the *swagger.json* file)? Is there a swagger log file that shows what/how it loads files?

**Things that work:**

- http://localhost:5002/swagger
- http://localhost:5002/static/swagger.json
- http://localhost:5002/static/components.json

So this proves the web server can find the static/components.json file.

**Part of swagger.json:**

```
  "components": {
    "schemas": {

      "id": {
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "number",
            "format": "int64"
          }
        }
      },

      "componentsPost": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/id"   <-- THIS WORKS
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "component_type_id": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/id"   <-- THIS WORKS
          },
          "system_type_id": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/id"   <-- THIS WORKS
          },
          "parent_id": {
            "$ref": "#/components/schemas/id"
          }
        },
        "example": {
            "$ref": "components.json"      <-- THIS DOES *NOT* WORK
        }
      },
```

> Note: components.json is different than the #components/schema/id
> reference, which is in the same file as shown above.

**Beginning of components.json data file:**

```
{
  "components": [
    {
      "id": 99999,
      "name": "root",
      "description": "Root Component",
      "component_type_id": 1,
      "system_type_id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "lan1",
      "description": "LAN",
      "component_type_id": 1,
      "system_type_id": 4,
      "parent_id": 99999
    },
```

The swagger.json file gets loaded but components.json does not:

```
[06/Jan/2021 12:32:53] "GET /static/swagger.json HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The swagger web site shows the $ref, not the expected components.json:
[image: swagger pic]

**Alternate code I have tried:**

```
        "example": {
            "components": {
                "$ref": "components.json"
            }
        }

        "example": {
            "$ref": "/static/components.json"
        }

        "example": {
            "$ref": "./static/components.json"
        }

        "example": {
            "$ref": "static/components.json"
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refer to an external JSON file containing response examples in Swagger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41393982/how-to-refer-to-an-external-json-file-containing-response-examples-in-swagger)

Comment: To recap the ^^ linked Q&A - the `example` keyword does NOT support $ref, it requires an inline example value. To reference external examples you can define request/response media type examples with `externalValue`. However, support for `externalValue` is [not yet available](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5433) in Swagger UI. The best solution for now is to use inline examples.